# adding items to the context menu on the extension icon

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm building a chrome extension that requires login.

I would like to have a 'logout' functionality on the context menu of the extension.

[image]

I know this question has been asked and answered, but i went through all of them and i guess they are all outdated.

I'm also positive that this can be done, by looking at extensions like Lastpass:

[image]

Comment: probably a duplicate but as i say in my question, that question was asked 6 years ago....

Comment: 99% of the extensions API hasn't changed since the very beginning.

Comment: so i guess i'm in the one percent

Comment: To be in 1% means something's not working so you need to provide [MCVE](/help/mcve) in the question.